# Fixtures seem to be ignored in Django tests

Tags: python, django, fixtures, pytest

I have a Django app which basically looks like this:

```
app/
    fixtures/
        file.json
    ...
    tests/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        tests.py
```

I have loaded my fixture in `tests.py`, which basically looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestFile(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['file.json']

    ...
```

My fixture file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "model": "sites.site", 
        "pk": 100, 
        "fields": {
          "domain": "myproject.mydomain.com", 
          "name": "My Project"
        }
    },
]
```

I have `django.contrib.sites` in my `settings.py` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

However, when I try to run my tests with py.test, this fixture seem to be ignored, since I break in some of my tests with `ipdb`, query for `Site.objects.all()`, and my fixture site isn't shown. What can be the problem?

I run my tests with: `py.test --ds=app.tests.settings --pyargs app.tests.tests -s` (`-s` is for allowing `ipdb`'s output).
`

Comment: do the fixtures load correctly using manage.py loaddata app/fixtures/file.jsson?

Comment: No, but I found that I have forgotten to include `app` in `INSTALLED_APPS`...now the fixture is installed and I can see my fixture site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was in fact a very obvious detail: I have forgotten to include `app` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in my `settings.py` file. The fixture is now installed and I can see my fixture site.